# Powershell script not starting java app correctly

Tags: powershell

Hello guys i am trying to create a powershell script to run my Java application with parameters. App starts and seems to be running but but i'm not getting expected output. I runned the code with params using Intelij and it was ok so the problem lies with powershell script not java code. Can you guys check it out maybe you can spot a mistake?

```
param
(
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $directory,
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateSet("bfs","dfs","astr")][string] $algorithm,
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $jarPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Repozytoria\FifteenPuzzle\target\Fifteenpuzzle-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
)

$fileRegex ="[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+.txt";

$files = Get-ChildItem $directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $fileRegex} | select FullName
$strategies = @("RDUL","RDLU","DRUL","DRLU","LUDR","LURD","ULDR","ULRD");
$heuristcs = @("hamm","manh");


if($algorithm -eq "astr")
{
    foreach($heuristc in $heuristcs)
    {
         foreach($file in $files)
         {

             $app = Start-Process java -ArgumentList "'-jar',$jarPath, $file, $algorithm, $heuristic" -PassThru

            $app.PriorityClass = "High"
            $app.WaitForExit()

         }
    }
}
else
{
    foreach($strategy in $strategies)
    {
        foreach($file in $files)
        {
           #$file
           $app = Start-Process java -ArgumentList "'-jar',$jarPath, $file, $algorithm, $strategy" -PassThru


           $app.WaitForExit()

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: `-ArgumentList '-jar',$jarPath, $file, $algorithm, $strategy`

Comment: I get this kind of error when i change the code as u said
 `Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the
 argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the
command again.`

Comment: In the `foreach()` loop you use `$heuristc` (missing an `i`) but in the `ArgumentList` you've spelled the variable name `$heuristic`

Comment: Ow man thanks a lot!! I always do mistakes like this. Thanks again mate!